# php date only show in first row

Tags: php

Good Day,

I have received this code to form a plugin for Ninja Forms. This code enables you to put the submissions of a form on the front end. Everything was working fine until we added a date function. This function is supposed to put the date in front of every row it creates. Unfortunately it only puts the date in front of the first row, the every row after that, the information moves one column to the left with no date.

```
<?php
function test_display_submissions( $args = array() ) {
    // $args = array(
    //   'form_id' => 1
    // );
    $form_id = $args['form_id'];
    $columns = $args['cols'];
    $columns = explode( ',', $columns );
    $sub_results = ninja_forms_get_subs( array( 'form_id' => $form_id ) );
    $plugin_settings = get_option("ninja_forms_settings");
    if(isset($plugin_settings['date_format'])){
        $date_format = $plugin_settings['date_format'];
    } else {
        $date_format = 'm/d/Y';
    }
    $content = '<table>
        <thead>
    <tr>';
    $content .= '<th>Date</th>';
    foreach ( $columns as $id ) {
        $field = ninja_forms_get_field_by_id( $id );
        if( isset( $field['data']['label'] ) ){
            $label = $field['data']['label'];
        } else {
            $label = '';
        }
        $content .= '<th>' . $label . '</th>';
    }
    $content .= '</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    $content .= '<td>' . date($date_format, strtotime($sub['date_updated'])) . '</td>';
    foreach ( $sub_results as $sub ) {
        $fields = $sub['data'];
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            $field_id = $field['field_id'];
            $user_value = $field['user_value'];
            if ( in_array( $field_id, $columns ) ) {
                $content .= '<td>' . $user_value . '</td>';
            }
        }
    $content .= '</tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</tbody>
    </table>';
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'display_subs', 'test_display_submissions' );
```

Comment: I would recommend you edit your question and remove the password. That can only lead to bad things.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the foreach loop. You need to place your date in the loop, not before :

```
    foreach ( $sub_results as $sub ) {
        // Display date
        $fields = $sub['data'];
        $content .= '<tr>';
        $content .= '<td>' . date($date_format, strtotime($sub['date_updated'])) . '</td>';
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            $field_id = $field['field_id'];
            $user_value = $field['user_value'];
            if ( in_array( $field_id, $columns ) ) {
                $content .= '<td>' . $user_value . '</td>';
            }
        }
        $content .= '</tr>';
    }
    $content .= '</tbody>
```

Comment: The foreach is incorrect here also. The <TD> should NOT be outside of the <TR>

Comment: Wow, thank you! I am not a php developer. May I please ask how the entire code would be written the right way?

Comment: also, for some reason it starts the date from 01/01/1970. Instead of the date it was submitted.

Comment: @user3256635 you need to post the $sub['date_updated'] information here. that 01/01/1970 date means something has gone wrong in the date() format function

Comment: wow, you guys know so much. I am completely lost on how to edit the code the right way, is there anybody that can assist me by correcting the loop please.

Answer (score 0):

You have the  beginning after you have the date added to the table.

It should be `<tbody><tr><td>DATE STUFF</td><td>MORE CONTENT</td></tr><tbody>`
in this format and your date column should be placed within your foreach loop.